# How would I use Regex to search and filter through an array of objects?

Tags: regex, typescript

Currently my data looks like

```js
   accountData =  [
  {accountNumber: 123, users: [{id: 1, email: 'xyz@aol.com', name: 'bob'},{id: 2, email: 'dfg@gmail.com', name: 'tomas'}],
  {accountNumber: 345, users: [{id: 3, email: 'abc@yahoo.com', name: 'mark'},{id: 4, email: 'dfg@gmail.com', name: 'peter'}, {id: 5, email: 'gdfgfgd@gmail.com', name: 'tom'}]
]
```

I have a search bar and I want to be able to search for 'tom' for example. If the user types 'tom' then both accounts should show up. However, if the user types 'tomas' then only accountNumber 123 should show up. Im not exactly sure how to filter these out with regex. My accountData has much more data in it so filtering it this way would be ideal.

I would need it to filter through anything in the array including accountNumber, id, email, and name.

Comment: Just a thought, you could serialize the object into JSON, and then apply the regex to that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Updated in response to comments

Use the `Array.map` function to filter out the parts of `accountData` that you do not want.

- First step in the map function is to filter out `users` that match the regular expression
- If there are no user matches, check for the other matches on `accountData`
- If there are no matches on account data, return `null`
- Finally, before printing using `console.log`, filter out any `null` results using `.filter(Boolean)`

In the example below `mapByExpression` creates a map function based on a `RegExp` that will filter the JSON representation as suggested by @Gavin. It isn't the most efficient way to achieve this, but it is simple.

Note that you should escaping RegExp characters when doing this. I've included an example which calls `escapeRegExp`.

```js
const accountData = [
  {accountNumber: 123, users: [{id: 1, email: 'xyz@aol.com', name: 'bob'},{id: 2, email: 'dfg@gmail.com', name: 'tomas'}]},
  {accountNumber: 345, users: [{id: 3, email: 'abc@yahoo.com', name: 'mark'}, {id: 4, email: 'dfg@gmail.com', name: 'peter'}, {id: 5, email: 'gdfgfgd@gmail.com', name: 'tom'}]}
];

function mapByExpression(expression) {
  return function(accountData) {
    let { users, ...otherFields } = accountData
    users = users.filter(user => expression.test(JSON.stringify(user)));
    if (users.length) {
      return {
        ...otherFields,
        users,
      };
    } else if (expression.test(JSON.stringify(otherFields))) {
      return accountData;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

console.log(accountData.map(mapByExpression(new RegExp(escapeRegExp('tom')))).filter(Boolean));
console.log(accountData.map(mapByExpression(new RegExp(escapeRegExp('tomas')))).filter(Boolean));
console.log(accountData.map(mapByExpression(new RegExp(escapeRegExp('123')))).filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: What if I search for `"users":[{`?

Comment: This works, and I know I didn't specify this earlier. But if a user is found, it should only return [ {accountNumber: xxx, users: {specific user only}} ] Right now its returning every user for the account number associated with the found user.

Comment: What would you do if it matches the account number? Which user should it return in that instance?

Comment: If it matches account number, itll return account number and all users. If it matches a user, itll return account number and that specific user only.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function search(searchTerm: string) {
  return accountData.filter(account =>
    account.users.some(user => 
      user.name.toLowerCase().includes(
        searchTerm.toLowerCase()
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: This only filters the name, I would need it to filter through anything in the object, including account number ,id , email, and name.

Comment: You can use
`users.some(user => Object.keys(user).some(key => user[key as keyof user].toString().toLowerCase().includes(...)) )`

Answer (score 0):

No need for Regex, a bit of Array methods will do:

```
const accountData = [
    { accountNumber: 123, users: [{ id: 1, email: 'xyz@aol.com', name: 'bob' }, { id: 2, email: 'dfg@gmail.com', name: 'tomas' }] },
    { accountNumber: 345, users: [{ id: 3, email: 'abc@yahoo.com', name: 'mark' }, { id: 4, email: 'dfg@gmail.com', name: 'peter' }, { id: 5, email: 'gdfgfgd@gmail.com', name: 'tom' }] }
]

const searchFilter = "tom";
const filteredData4 = accountData
    .filter(acc => acc.users.some(user => Object.values(user).some(val => val.toString().includes(searchFilter))));
```

Comment: Right. Edited the answer.